# Why is this SQL update query returning rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm running the following update command

```
UPDATE table
SET [End] = '2018-12-17'
WHERE (ID = '5b010204-c12c-4b38-8d28-affe11684da0')
```

This will give the following result:

 [image]

What can cause this on SQL server 14?

Comment: There are update triggers updating some other records in the table when the [end] column is updated.  Is there some way to not return these rows?

Comment: Fix the trigger so that it doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to an `UPDATE` trigger that has a `SELECT` in it. Modify the trigger so that it doesn't return any rows.